# Can't replace "\" into "/"

Tags: python

I have a code where I try to get a path from an input so this program could append info to another text file.

```
file1 = input("Input the file path:\n")
file2 = file1.replace("\", "/")
```

```
file2 = file1.replace("\", "/")
                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I get this problem and it seems to be because the \ is not seen as a string (if I put \n for example it does work but I need to replace )

An alternative for replacing \ with / could also fix my problem. I used to use r"filepath" but I can't do that with an input I think. I just need to make the input into a raw string.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `.replace`. A string literal can not end with a backslash because it escapes the closing `'` or `"`. You need to escape the backslash with a second backslash (`'\\'`)

Comment: `input()` already returns a "raw string". You should use `os.path` or `Pathlib` to deal with fllepath creation rather than replacing+appending strings